# How can I pass a directory argument to this fzf/ripgrep bash script for previewing search results?

Tags: bash

fzf/ripgrep can search an alternate directory from the command line with something like.

rg something ./sompath | fzf

The fzf documentation has a nice little bash script for generating a preview of rg's results that I call with a shell alias and then open the file with vim:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

RG_PREFIX="rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case "
INITIAL_QUERY="${*:-}"
IFS=: read -ra selected < <(
  FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="$RG_PREFIX $(printf %q "$INITIAL_QUERY")" \
  fzf --ansi \
      --color "hl:-1:underline,hl+:-1:underline:reverse" \
      --disabled --query "$INITIAL_QUERY" \
      --bind "change:reload:sleep 0.1; $RG_PREFIX {q} || true" \
      --bind "alt-enter:unbind(change,alt-enter)+change-prompt(2. fzf> )+enable-search+clear-query" \
      --prompt '1. ripgrep> ' \
      --delimiter : \
      --preview "$BAT_CMD --color=always {1} --highlight-line {2}" \
      --preview-window 'up,60%,border-bottom,+{2}+3/3,~3'
)
[ -n "${selected[0]}" ] && nvim  "${selected[0]}" "+${selected[1]}"
```

It's very cool and works great. Unfortunately, there's no way to pass in a directory argument into this script. So you have to cd into the desired directory, do the search, and cd back.

Instead, I'd like to do something like this:

`search_script initial_query ./some_dir`

But my bash skills are weak and I'm not really sure what the best approach is for processing an optional directory argument.

The script has to somehow be smart enough to recognize when a directory argument is passed and when it isn't. I'm not sure if some kind of option string like `--dir` is the best way to go or what. And I'm wondering if I might be missing something really obvious solution, too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to cargo cult some little bash snippets and piece something that seems to do the trick and detect if last argument is a directory:

```
RG_PREFIX="rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case "

INITIAL_QUERY="${*:-}"
last="${@: -1}"
if [[ -d $last ]]; then
  INITIAL_QUERY="${@:1:$#-1}";
  dir=$last
  echo $INITIAL_QUERY
fi
IFS=: read -ra selected < <(
  FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="$RG_PREFIX $(printf %q "$INITIAL_QUERY") $dir" \
  fzf --ansi \
      --color "hl:-1:underline,hl+:-1:underline:reverse" \
      --disabled --query "$INITIAL_QUERY" \
      --bind "change:reload:sleep 0.1; $RG_PREFIX {q} $dir || true" \
      --bind "alt-enter:unbind(change,alt-enter)+change-prompt(2. fzf> )+enable-search+clear-query" \
      --prompt '1. ripgrep> ' \
      --delimiter : \
      --preview "bat --color=always {1} --highlight-line {2}" \
      --preview-window 'up,60%,border-bottom,+{2}+3/3,~3'
)
[ -n "${selected[0]}" ] && nvim  "${selected[0]}" "+${selected[1]}"
```

If you think there is a simpler way or a better, I'd love to hear.